# SharePoint 2013 Apps Model Difference

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Below are my understanding on SharePoint 2013 Apps Model,

- SharePoint-Hosted Apps - It supports only JSOM and REST
- Auto-Hosted Apps & Provider-Hosted - It supports CSOM, JSOM and REST

Am I correct?

I was little confused about JSOM and CSOM also. Below are my understanding,

- JSOM - Javascript code which will be written in .js file.
- CSOM - C# code which can be written in code behind in Host Web.

Please let me know whether my understandings are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSOM stands for Client Object Model. There are three implementations of the Client Object Model: one for .NET managed code (VB, C#), one for Silverlight, and one for JavaScript. The JavaScript implementation of the Client Object Model is often referred to as JSOM.

SharePoint-Hosted Apps can only use JavaScript code. They communicate back to SharePoint using the JavaScript Client Object Model (JSOM) or the REST API.

Provider-Hosted Apps can use managed code but they cannot use the Server Object Model. They communicate back to SharePoint using either the managed or JavaScript Client Object Model or the REST API.